# How to create ManyToOne relationship using JPA Hibernate annotation?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, javabeans

I had two POJO class named Task and Team.A team can have many tasks correspondingly but each task can be mapped only one team.

```
// Task POJO
@Entity
@Table(name = "Task")
public class Task extends Domain implements Serializable {

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Id
private Long taskId;

//Mapping To Team 
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="teamId")
private Team teamId;
```

Team POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Team")
public class Team extends Domain implements Serializable {

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Id
private Long teamId;
@Column(nullable = false)

@OneToMany(mappedBy="teamId")
private List<Task> task = new ArrayList<Task>();
```

The issue is I couldn't  Map/Save/Update and which is not affecting my Team Pojo.

```
  //Task Table
  +-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
  +-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | taskId          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
  | taskName        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
  | teamId          | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
  +-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The Team Table

```
 +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | teamId   | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | teamName | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So How do I map these two Pojo classes and affect when saving/deletion of data in the tables.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what DBMS you are using?

Comment: @YCF_L  I am Using My-SQL with JPA and Spring

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that you have defined @Column at the one to many association property (tasks), I assume it was a type error.

For bi-directional one to many association, updates one side of the relationship, the other side should also get updated, and be in sync. Below shown how the make both entity in sync:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Task")
public class Task extends Domain implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long taskId;

    //Mapping To Team 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="teamId")
    private Team team;

    public void setTeam(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
        if (!team.getTasks().contains(this)) { 
            team.getTasks().add(this);
        }
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Team")
public class Team extends Domain implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long teamId;
    @Column(nullable = false)

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="team")
    private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();

    public void addTask(Task task) {
        this.tasks.add(task);
        if (task.getTeam() != this) {
            task.setTeam(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@OneToMany(mappedBy="teamId", cascade=CascadeType.ALL), try to add this annotation above the member(attribute) task of the class Team

Comment: i just posted as a answer because i haven't permissions to comment, well, i have an old source code, and it works fine for me, https://github.com/lucasfantacuci/spring-jpa-one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

Complete your @manyToOne mapping in the Task entity by adding the referenced column in the Team entity; and also name the member as 'team', not 'teamId' i.e.:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="teamId",
   referencedColumnName="teamId")
private Team team;
```

To understand relationship mapping in JPA in general, see this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices